# Material-UI React "Print" Breakpoint

Tags: material-ui

I've started using breakpoint specific code for in particular fontSizes like so;

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTypography: {
      headline: {
        fontSize: pxToRem(24),
        [breakpoints.up("md")]: {
          fontSize: pxToRem(32)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This works fine/great when you're working with screen Sizes, but is there a way to do a similar solution for media breakpoints like 'print'. i.e. am i able to control fontSizes when @media (print) = true, as well as @media (min-width: x)

Answer (score 0):

can use the 'freeform' query to do this; `@media <your query>`

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTypography: {
      headline: {
        fontSize: pxToRem(24),
        [breakpoints.up("md")]: {
          fontSize: pxToRem(32)
        },
        '@media print': {
          fontSize: 11pt
        }
      }
    }
  }
```